# $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-s} X_{k+s}X_{k}$ the same as $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k+s}X_{k}$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, asymptotics, time-series

I need to show that 
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-s} X_{k+s}X_{k}$$
for some number $s$ is essentially the same (asymptotically negligible) as
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k+s}X_{k}$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$, for a zero-mean time series $(X_t)$.

First, I know that $\frac{n-s}{n}$ goes to $1$ very rapidly (sublinearly, even logarithmically ). If I write them as a fraction then
$$ \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n-s} X_{k+s}X_{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_{k+s}X_{k}}=\frac{ \sum_{k=1}^{n-s} X_{k+s}X_{k}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-s} X_{k+s}X_{k} + \sum_{k=n+1-s}^{n} X_{k+s}X_{k}}$$
Then $\sum_{k=n+1-s}^{n} X_{k+s}X_{k}$ goes to zero az $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Is this enough of an argument? It seems to me that is very simple, but I can say the same for the question? Any ideas?

Thank you!

EDIT: $(X_t)$ are (wlog) with zero mean and $\mathbb{E} [X_{t+s}X_t]$ exists and it is finite for all $s$, and does not depend on $t$.

Comment: In which way should they be essentially the same? Do you consider pointwise convergence or convergence in distribution/probability (as $n \to \infty$)?

Comment: That they will have the same asymptotic properties. Nothing more is said. Both sums are used as an estimator of the auto-covariance function of the time series.

The whole goal is to study asymptotic normality of first estimator, using the second one. 

The direct question is: show that in order to study asymptotic normality of (first sum), it suffices to establish asymptotic normality of (second sum).

Comment: Are there some assumption on the $X_t$? For example, do they admit moments of order $2$?

Comment: Yes, the series is (second-order) stationary, and nothing more is known. In summary, they are (wlog) zero-mean, and $\mathbb{E} [X_{t+s} X_t]$ exist and that do not depend on $t$. How is this going to effect the sum if we only change (the last) $s$ terms in sequence growing in numbers to infinity? As $n \rightarrow \infty$ it looks to me that the sums are the same, but as I said above this does not sound as a very good argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $s \in \mathbb{N}$, and set

$$Y_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-s} X_{k+s} X_k \qquad \qquad Z_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n X_{k+s} X_k.$$

Obviously, we have

$$Y_n = \frac{n-s}{n} Z_{n-s}. \tag{1}$$

We want to show that $$Y_n \stackrel{d}{\to} Y  \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad Z_n \stackrel{d}{\to} Y \tag{2}$$ where $d$ denotes convergence in distribution and $Y$ is an abritrary random variable. To see this we note the following two facts.

1. $Z_{n-s} \stackrel{d}{\to} Y \Leftrightarrow Z_n \stackrel{d}{\to} Y$; this follows straight from the definition of convergence in distribution (recall that $s$ is fixed).
2. If $X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} \mu$ and $(a_n)_n$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $a_n \to a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $a_n \cdot X_n \stackrel{d}{\to} a \cdot X$.

Combining these two, we get $(2)$ from $(1)$.

Comment: Does the speed of convergence of $frac{n-s}{n}$ matters? This is the same as asking if the size of $s$ matters?

Comment: @Cherufe In which sense "matter"? Roughly speaking, one could say that $Z_n$ does contain more information about the process than $Y_n$ (in $Z_n$ we use the information up to time $n+s$ whereas $Y_n$ does only depend on $X_1,\ldots,X_n$)... the larger $s$, the large the difference between those two.